# Java simple-json's parser make a mess with variables

Tags: java, json, simplejson

> { "period" : 5, "externs" : { "lots" : { "start" : 1, "step" : 0, "stop" : 2 } } }

I'm trying to convert the above JSON string to a JSONObject using simple-json. I do it by:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONParser().parse(str);
```

the problem is that the parser somehow change the variables order to:

> { "externs" : { "lots" : { "stop" : 2 , "start" : 1 , "step" : 0 } } , "period" : 5 }

And I want to keep the exactly same order as in the beginning , any hints?

Comment: I failed to google out SimpleJSON. Is it [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv

Comment: Since JSONObject allows you to get() them in any order does it matter? And as @Kevinbowersox points out, JSON is an unordered collection.

Comment: @Nikolay yes I meant json-simple. And I understand JSON's philosophy but, isn't it weird that if you give the parser a JSON it just mess around with your string **arbitrary**?

Comment: JSON is unordered.  You do not need to preserve order.

Comment: @DwB, that was already mentioned. There are, however, use cases to come up with to retain the order of the json (string). For example, say you want to add some key/values to a json-config file and save it back to disk. It would be annoying if the order of the keys in such a file is messed up after each edit.

Comment: That is the problem I was facing, reading a .json with an order and trying to keep that order while saving those values in an .cvs file.

Comment: @BartKiers Hi Bart, could you explain how it could be a problem? Since  with org.json.JSONObject you can get the keys out in any order using a get(String key) what difference does it make what order they're stored in? I'm trying to wrap my head around how it would be a problem. Let's take your case: you load the file into a string and parse it with a JSON parser (or JSONObject). You then get an iterator with keys() or you just call get() to retrieve the values you need.

Comment: @mttdbrd, like I said: the json file could be a config file which you might edit manually. And when editing it manually, you'd like to be able to find the entries in the same place, right? I know I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want opposes how JSON objects are specified: an *unordered* list of key/value pairs.

Comment: I didn't mean to break the law, but if I run a hundred times that code, It'll return the same string in the same order, so it has an order, I just want for it to keep the same order as in the root JSON string.

Comment: @omarloren, the fact that a certain implementation (simple-json, in your case) parses it each time in the same order does not mean said implementation does so with a specific goal in mind. Chances are a HashMap is returned, in which case the "order" (which I cannot call it) is based on the hash code of the keys. Also see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938442/how-to-parse-from-json-to-map-with-json-simple-and-retain-key-order

Comment: @BartKiers Thank you I solve it with the link provided